# is there a "direct" way to get boolean values from input checkboxes with FormData?

Tags: javascript

is it a better way than to do that ?

[update after
[**VLAZ**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76979022/is-ther-a-direct-way-to-get-boolean-values-from-input-checkboxes-with-formdata?noredirect=1#comment135704140_76979022) comment ]
see button code -> `if (myForm[key].type === 'checkbox')`
But I'm still wondering if a better code is possible..?

```js
const
  lsKey    = 'local_storage_key'
, myForm   = document.querySelector('#my-form')
//, savDatas = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem(lsKey) || '[]' )
, savDatas = [];
  ;
myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()
  let respObj = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(myForm).entries());

  // add properties with empty value for unchecked checkBox
  respObj.truc             ??= '';
  // respObj.otherChBxName ??= '';

  savDatas[0] = respObj; // savDatas.push( respObj );

  // localStorage.setItem(lsKey, JSON.stringify( savDatas ));
  myForm.reset();
  
  console.clear()
  console.log( JSON.stringify( respObj ));
  }
function restoreSaved() // 
  {
  if (savDatas.length)
    Object.keys(savDatas[0]).forEach( key => 
      {
      if (myForm[key].type === 'checkbox')
        myForm[key].checked = (myForm[key].value === savDatas[0][key]);
      else
        myForm[key].value = savDatas[0][key];
      });
  }
```

```css
label,
button {
  display: block;
  margin: .7em 1em;
}
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <label> 
    name :
    <input type="name" name="name" value="" required>
  </label>
  <label> 
    truc :
    <input type="checkbox" name="truc" value="truc">
  </label>
  <label><!--other checkbox entrie 2--></label>
  <label><!--other text entrie 3--></label>
  <!-- ... -->
  <label><!--other entrie N--></label>
  <button>save</button>
</form>

<button onclick="restoreSaved();">restore data</button>
```

Comment: I don't think so. `FormData` is designed based on the way forms are submitted. and unchecked boxes don't get submitted to the server.

Comment: If "truc" is not checked there will be no `respObj.truc` in other words. If there is, that means the input was checked, and the value of the property is the value of the input, not `true`.

Comment: Better in what respect? I'd personally consider `checked` to be OK but I am not sure what needs to be improved.

Comment: @VLAZ it is in the case where we want to reset a dialogue-form from LocalStorage data, the checkboxes pose a problem...

Comment: I mean, yeah - they do. I had to deal with this just last week. I just ended up having a custom value extractor to put into local storage and value restorer to get the value back into the form element. I used the type of the input element for that. I also needed some custom handling for few others like dates and dropdowns (since those were Select2 elements). Essentially, I did `if (formElement.type === "checkbox") formElement.checked = localStorage.get(formElement.id)` and the opposite for writing.

Comment: @VLAZ I have updated my question regarding your comment.

Comment: Since FormData returns checkboxes that have been checked and those values are being saved into localStorage, couldn't you use something like this? Unchecked checkboxes aren't being saved, so if a checkbox is saved, you know its true. `myForm.querySelector("[name='" + key + "'][value='" + savDatas[0][key] + "']").checked = true;`

Comment: @imvain2 yes, I have already used this type of solution, even with a personal wrapper, but I prefer to forget that, having a standard code is always better, and this is precisely the meaning of my question:   I would like the formData be better thought out. After all, with HTML5 form's management  has already evolved greatly, but there is still work to do!